# slicing python array elements with a vector similar to matlab/R

Tags: python

I'm new to python and wanted to do something I normally do in matlab/R all the time, but couldn't figure it out from the docs.

I'd like to slice an array not as 0:3 which includes elements 0,1,2 but as an explicit vector of indices such as 0,3
For example, say I had this data structure

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

I'd like the second and third element
so I thought something like this would work

```
a[list(1,3)]
```

but that gives me this error

> TypeError: list indices must be
>   integers

This happens for most other data types as well such as numpy arrays

In matlab, you could even say a[list(2,1)] which would return this second and then the first element.

There is an alternative implementation I am considering, but I think it would be slow for large arrays. At least it would be damn slow in matlab. I'm primarily using numpy arrays.

```
[ a[i] for i in [1,3] ]
```

What's the python way oh wise ones? 
Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[NumPy](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html) allows you to use lists as indices:

```
import numpy
a = numpy.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
a[[1, 3]]
```

Note that this makes a copy instead of a view.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you want [numpy.take](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.take.html):

```
newA = numpy.take(a, [1,3])
```